# How can I have an NSTimer going throughout the entire time the user is in the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, background, nstimer, background-process

How can I have an NSTimer going throughout the entire time the user is in the app?

I want to be able to change view controllers and perform different functions, all while a timer is going on int the background.  If the timer hits 0, then I want to fire an event.  Can I also have a timer going inside the app while the app is in the background?  Or even when the iPhone's screen is off?

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You can take that Timer in App delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this method in app delegate

```
-(void) timerfunc{
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.5) target:self selector:@selector(yourfunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES ];
    [pool release];

}
```

Comment: When should I call this method?

Comment: - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

Answer (score 2):

Do this piece of code in the Appdelegate making the timer its property.

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:intervalForTimer
                                                    target: self
                                                  selector: @selector(timerExpired:)
                                                  userInfo: nil
                                                   repeats: NO];

   //Run the timer on the runloop to ensure that it works when app is in background
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]addTimer:self.timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```